# Parsing XML File into SQL Server database returns 0 rows

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am an XML newb and so this relatively small project is causing me grief.
I have the XML into a temp table data type XML and that works just fine.

I have found an example of how to then parse the xml into rows and columns however when I have set up a test of just 2 columns - I get 0 results when I am expecting 2 rows.

Can anyone assist please?

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = xmldata FROM tempXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT TransactionType, TransactionDate
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Handoff/ImmediateDetail')
WITH 
(
    TransactionType [VarChar](50) '@TransactionType',
    TransactionDate datetime '@TransactionDate'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Sample XML:

```
<my:Handoff> 
    <ImmediateDetail OrderItemRef="1032355" TransactionType="Issue" 
                     TransactionDate="2016-09-29T12:22:00></ImmediateDetail>
</my:Handoff>
```

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Can you give us an example of the xml you are attempting to parse?

Comment: Hi yes  - I have cut it down for reasons of data security.

Comment: <my:Handoff >
      <ImmediateDetail OrderItemRef="1032355"         TransactionType="Issue" TransactionDate="2016-09-29T12:22:00>
      </ImmediateDetail>

    </my:Handoff>

Comment: I got undeclared prefix so I removed the "my:"  and there was a missing quote at the end of the date - but then it ran just fine.  <Handoff > <ImmediateDetail OrderItemRef="1032355" TransactionType="Issue" TransactionDate="2016-09-29T12:22:00"> </ImmediateDetail> </Handoff>

Comment: Well, obviously there's an XML namespace with the prefix of `my` in play - but you're not showing what it's defined at , in your sample XML :....

Comment: Marc_s sadly it is not obvious, as I previously stated, I am a newb at this so a little patience would be appreciated.

Comment: What difference does the my make and how should I handle it?

Comment: Namespaces help you avoid naming conflicts..if you don't plan on encountering conflicts you can omit them however it's easier to add them in upfront rather than to retrofit later.

Comment: That XML namespace ought to be **defined** somewhere in the XML document - something like `<root xmlns:my="........" >`. If you don't have anything like that for the `my` prefix, then you probably only have a **fragment** of a XML document - not a whole document. You will need to strip the `my:` prefixes from the textual representation, since there's no declared namespace to go with this

Answer (score 2):

If your XML didn't have any XML namespace, then you could use this code to retrieve the data (and insert it into the SQL Server table):

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<Handoff> 
                        <ImmediateDetail OrderItemRef="1032355" TransactionType="Issue" TransactionDate="2016-09-29T12:22:00" />
                    </Handoff>'

SELECT
    OrderItemRef = XC.value('@OrderItemRef', 'bigint'),
    TransactionType = XC.value('@TransactionType', 'varchar(50)'),
    TransactionDate = XC.value('@TransactionDate', 'datetime')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/Handoff/ImmediateDetail') AS XT(XC)
```

If your XML document does have an XML namespace - then you need to **use it** and include it in your query:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('.....' as my)
SELECT
    OrderItemRef = XC.value('@OrderItemRef', 'bigint'),
    TransactionType = XC.value('@TransactionType', 'varchar(50)'),
    TransactionDate = XC.value('@TransactionDate', 'datetime')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/my:Handoff/my:ImmediateDetail') AS XT(XC)
```

Comment: Cheers - I was trying the pre 2005 route without using nodes - however maybe I need to go back to the drawing board. XT(XC) is confusing - what does this bit do?  Dave

Comment: @DaveEdmonds: the `.nodes()` function returns a "pseudo table" with one column of XML type - the `XT` stands as the **table alias** for that pseudo table, and the `XC` is the column name for that XML typed column in that pseudo table

Comment: @DaveEdmonds: well yes - if you *do have* a definition for the XML namespace that uses the `my:` prefix - then you need to use **that string** in this place here - since you haven't shown that namespace definition, I cannot possibly know what that is, so therefore the `.....` ...

Comment: I know it - that's fine thank you for your help. Dave

Comment: `
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = xmldata FROM tempXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.example.com' as my)

SELECT
    OrderItemRef = XC.value('@OrderItemRef', 'bigint'),
    TransactionType = XC.value('@TransactionType', 'varchar(50)'),
    TransactionDate = XC.value('@TransactionDate', 'datetime')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/my:Handoff/my:ImmediateDetail') AS XT(XC)
    
    
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO`

Comment: @DaveEdmonds: you **MUST have** a semicolon before the `WITH` keyword ....

Comment: @DaveEdmonds: also please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: apologies for code errors - still learning how this site works.

Comment: @DaveEdmonds: can you please post the full code and full XML sample in your question? It works just fine for me - **IF** the XML document actually does contain the XML namespace declaration ...

Comment: Will do - Thought I had but maybe it didn't post.

Comment: PS Can the table and column aliases be anything or are XC and XT reserved? I need to add multiple nodes eventually.  Dave

Comment: @DaveEdmonds: those aliases are totally up to you - that's just my habit to call them  `XT` and `XC` - but they could be anything, really

Comment: Cool thanks for that - I added a second mode but am now getting duplicates - will select distinct solve it or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is probably something wrong with the contents of the table tempXML.

I just ran this code:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = '<Handoff><ImmediateDetail OrderItemRef="1032355" TransactionType="Issue" TransactionDate="2016-09-29T12:22:00"> </ImmediateDetail> </Handoff>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT TransactionType,TransactionDate
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Handoff/ImmediateDetail')
WITH 
(
TransactionType [VarChar](50) '@TransactionType',
TransactionDate datetime '@TransactionDate'

)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

and I got this result

```
TransactionType TransactionDate
Issue           2013-06-21 13:50:00.000
```

which is what I would expect...

Any chance you could give us more details about tempXml or the data therein?

Here is some basic reading material on XML Namespaces

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. TempXml contains the xml I posted as a 1 line xml field that is imported from the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = xmldata FROM tempXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.example.com' as my)

SELECT
    OrderItemRef = XC.value('@OrderItemRef', 'bigint'),
    TransactionType = XC.value('@TransactionType', 'varchar(50)'),
    TransactionDate = XC.value('@TransactionDate', 'datetime')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/my:Handoff/ImmediateDetail') AS XT(XC)


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Solved!!! Many thanks one and all!!
Dave

Comment: Now that you're using the built-in XQuery support using `.nodes()`, you don't need those memory leaking `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` calls anymore - just toss those out